# Phaser Weapon plugin, set the kill_DISTANCE

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using the phaser weapon plugin, and i've set the kill type to kill_distance:

```
weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_DISTANCE;
```

But, it is automatically set to 2, which doesn't really allow it to travel very far. I'm wondering how i can set it to a larger number

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the [bulletKillDistance](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Weapon.html#bulletKillDistance):

```
weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_DISTANCE;
weapon.bulletKillDistance = 50;
```

This strikes me as [an oversight in the documentation](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/issues/601).

### Update

[This has been updated in the documentation source](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/commit/a7aa792c1c918345493f9317f365fdf09cc00e1f), and should be updated online once there's a release/deployment.

Answer (score 1):

> [static] KILL_DISTANCE : integer
>   A bulletKillType constant that automatically kills the bullets after they
>   exceed the bulletDistance from their original firing position.

Unfortunately, I tried searching in documents, but I could not find "bulletDistance". For example, if you use KILL_LIFESPAN, you can change bulletLifespan variable, but there are no "bulletDistance" in document. This is either not implemented or they forgot it in the docs. Try this and it may/may not work.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to KILL_LIFESPAN, and tried to set bulletLifespan, but it doesn't seem to work:
    weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_LIFESPAN;
    bulletLifespan = 1;

Am i doing this wrong?

Comment: Did you do weapon.bulletLifespan = 1; ? or bulletLifespan = 1; ? It should be the former one.